# jquery get one object in an array as an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

With jQuery I can do

```
$('#some_id').find('div').first()
```

or

```
$('#some_id').find('div').last()
```

and get an answer like

```
[<div>​something</div>​]
```

If I do

```
$('#some_id').find('div')[3]
```

I get answer like

```
<div>​something</div>
```

How do I specify an index in array and get an array just with that object?

I would love to do something like

```
$('#some_id').find('div').somefunc(3)
```

and get

```
[<div>​something</div>]
```

I know there is slice(), but I feel like there is some simpler function that I have over looked in my hours of searching.

I know there is :nth-child() but again, it feels like there is some other function that I can call the way I call first() or last().

I am trying to chain some functions together to have one line that does what I need.

If there is not other ways, then I guess that is fine.  I just wanted to make sure.

Thanks!

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use **[.eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq/)**:

```
$('#some_id').find('div').eq(3) // This will return the fourth div inside #some_id
```

Since `.eq()` is 0-based index, if you want to get the third div you need to use:

```
$('#some_id').find('div').eq(2)
```

Comment: Thanks!  I was searching for hours and then 2 minutes after I posted this, I found it.  But since your answer is correct, you get the check. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [`.get(index)`](http://api.jquery.com/get/)

```
$($('#some_id').find('div').get(3)); // jQuery obj
```

or

```
[$('#some_id').find('div').get(3)]; // Array
```

> The .get() method grants access to the DOM nodes underlying each
>   jQuery object. If the value of index is out of bounds — less than the
>   negative number of elements or equal to or greater than the number of
>   elements — it returns undefined.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer.  To my understanding get() gets the element, not an array with the element.